# requests library returns random-length HTML comment on a url that works on my browser

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape some data from (https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13496), but the request returns a random-length HTML comment. Actually, the original link is (https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13496.A_Game_of_Thrones), which does work fine, but the thing is that I want to make a loop to get data from many different books, and for that I thought of increasing the number at the end (.../show/), which I can't do if I use the full link. Any ideas why this isn't working?

```
import requests
website_url = requests.get("https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13496").text
website_url
```

output:

`'\n<!-- This is a random-length HTML comment: dbfcoiufztspijeplzetzgnsmgqafdebmxdhdwymdkcwlapjrxcmifztgxftkxopbfnrmsnjlwejxsvjhwcgyucllxwjxhorhozhiswmleonkzkderiistzezaacrsnfxkmwgwgtrshvkvrwohppyeuoigeyvufdofuvqzbtxfzqfvhtzsgllopgfnrsoosstzyslmoqqxxxtgvnmvdlcqeugrisnqlbuzgnfuftkkthwgkjnszdjpgcpqbdydwzdodfwhvgrcqclusdybxdamaqmvgrxkpmoabcplokgcegnoargghnnkdujujdbiiqhoslxlkasaibahfcrremhovfilyczqrzeaztekckwqzwhchrnjnlgjxkmaxcjrsljhqnidhxeuogpwppzqsglbfbbpogosmzirnngflmhoptbagwphngnvbwtgzubeqvojxtnsmkttmskvrsnybtgvxuipokljhzkwidvucetwpwikekuggsvghnwnvatxjsqqsvjrlnoiwyybqlhhyvdlpghvqtxkujhghcnqgsbtkrxdiulgwppscwqrdipilwazunzbdcjlydfhjqelrzfhotjwuxoicncvihigexnasgmbpjwfqrxfcbzfyvgkjczxfjnwoavqcxnniqnhboimpnsdcgsxtdpovxedtgtgouutogvasqqoxxrmwdpcbqryknfalavghthfmotqehlgfuxxibdroncprlfjbuiywhvzvranyscnnrpwnogkbasvelyhhhabgcrwszeidlmgswlxnltpdeolrromyauqoonuiemgtrtccvewikdsfhroknbmatcwmvaybsfpyemchbhqxsoxpyscdmvxmttdtkfoaqmmjlfmbjmxpcdaizfbspexpydmbgqmoscdjddmdyhgonfuofcjxvfbvhfxfwlmlizvmvtmrfodawtghytrcuksybdkcfvhsyqwsruqppzahunkkszasuncbhwtjvbyagsaxkrusoihjxjebwyozpfozxnckvhynlmanfwkabqgklchpqwulelddvugxfzjaxmiputfwxoadvrswwbxcltrqktynsfpceygfgskggodhajguzoznkcrzonrxawzuuuaoxpaflrsybrgiepblbqkoikwepgxzmzuscgx -->'`

```
import requests
website_url = requests.get("https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13496.A_Game_of_Thrones").text
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url,"lxml")
title_and_author = soup.head.title.string
title_and_author
```

output:

`'\nA Game of Thrones by George R.R. Martin\n'`

The loop is

```
for i in range(1,n):
    # Gets the url, we get a different book for every value of i
    website_url = requests.get("https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/" + str(i)).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url,"lxml")
```

Comment: Have you looked through https://www.goodreads.com/api ? Using the API will be a cleaner solution than scraping.

Comment: OMG I didn't even think about an API! I was just starting to learn webscraping so I was playing around a bit with different websites, but using an API makes much more sense for this. Thanks!